# Prestashop Handle post data in custom CMS form

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've developped a prestashop module that display a form, and now I want to use the POST data to store my data in the database.

Following some tutorials I'm able to display the form and load some js file, but my question are two:

- What will be the action parameter of my form?
- How can i handle the post parameters, and where??

The structure of my module is this - root is /modules/mymodule/ dir:

- mymodule.php
- /views/templates/hook/mymodule.tpl
- /views/js/front.js

Have i to insert a controller??

Thank you.

**EDIT- Add some code**

mymodule.php

```
class MyModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymodule';
        $this->controllers = array( 'display' ); // <- my controller name

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function install()
    {
       if (Shop::isFeatureActive())
         Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);

       if (!parent::install() ||
         !$this->registerHook('customCMS') ||
         !$this->registerHook('header')
       )
          return false;

       return true;
     }

    public function hookcustomCMS($params)
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('id_cms') != 7)
            return;

      $this->context->smarty->assign(
          array(
              'form_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
          )
      );

      return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
    }
}
```

mymodule.tpl

```
<form id="myform" action="{$link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')|escape:'html'}" method="post">
<!-- all fields...  + submit button -->
</form>
```

display.php (this shoul be the controller in mymodule/controllers/front)

```
<?php
class mymoduledisaplyFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{


    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();


        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->module->getLocalPath().'views/js/front.js');
        $this->setTemplate('mymodule.tpl');
    }



    public function postProcess()
    {
      if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_requestform'))
      {
          // form processing

          ppp("OK");


      }
    }

}
```

That's all...

Comment: What is this form? Module configuration? Front page? Admin page? If it's front page or admin page yes you need a controller. You need to provide more information and some code as well so we can help you further.

Comment: @TheDrot I've edited the post adding my code. Should be a front controller. My scope is adding a form with some fields and logic and store the data in the database. I've omitted some unuseful code like configs.

Comment: Class declaration of controller is wrong. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491693/prestashop-module-with-controller-throws-404/40492153#40492153) for proper declaration.

Comment: @TheDrot That solved the calling flow. Not I can proceed  with my development!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answers to your questions below:

- What will be the action parameter of my form?

The action parameter for your form will be

```
$this->smarty->assign('action', 'index.php?controller=AdminModules&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules').'&configure='.$this->name)
```

You need to assign it to smarty from your controller (mymodule.php) in getContent() function and then you can use it as action in your TPL file.

- How can I handle the post parameters, and where??

You can get the values of your post parameters in mymodule.php - getContent() function by using the following code:

```
$post_param = Tools::getValue('name_of_parameter');
```

Answer (score 1):

If only get the specific value (POST+GET), you can use:

```
Tools::getValue('param');
```

If you want to get all values from POST + GET please use:

```
Tools::getAllValues();
```

And also refer from [prestashop_folder]/class/Tools.php

Answer (score 0):

To get posted data from the form you have to use

```
Tools::getValue('PARAM_NAME');
```

And to insert data to Database you should use

```
Configuration::updateValue('PARAM_NAME', Tools::getValue('PARAM_NAME'));
```

To get Values from Database of your params use

```
Configuration::get('PARAM_NAME');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a front controller. You can just submit your form to actual CMS URL and manipulate POST data inside your hookcustomCMS($params) function.

```
    public function hookcustomCMS($params)
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('id_cms') != 7)
            return;
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit_requestform'))
        {
              //form proccessing
        }

      $this->context->smarty->assign(
          array(
              'form_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
          )
      );

      return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
    }
```

Comment: this seems working but i found my solution following @TheDort advice in previous commen.