# How to save form data to database?

Tags: prestashop

I'm making 'Offer your price' module. I made a form where user have to fill his name, email and offered price. I want to save form data into the database. So the question is what is the correct way of doing that?

Comment: @MicSel I'm talking about prestashop :)

Comment: here is similar question might help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762425/prestashop-handle-post-data-in-custom-cms-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your module:

1- add new table to save data

2- add new Class (objectModel) to communicate with your table

3- add new front page (frontController) on your module and send form data to your front page

4- save data and other actions